# $_POST not working on localhost

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I apologize in advance, I am extremely new to PHP (couple of days)

I have been trying to figure out why when I press submit my code is not working. If I use the test to see if $_POST is working, it works, but when I try to get a variable, it does not work.

This is the top half of my form. I omitted most of it because it is long, but each bracket does have a closing bracket.

```
<div id="app">
<form action="submit.php" method="POST" id ="app_form">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Student Information:</legend>
    First Name <input type="text" name="first_name">
```

Submit.php looks like...

```
<?php

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
  echo "Hello!";
  echo $_POST["first_name"];
}
?>
```

Everytime I test it it will print Hello but it will not print the first name variable at all.

Comment: Do you get any error ?

Comment: Try print_r($_POST) below echo "Hello". Do you see first_name in this array?

Comment: and what contains your $_POST ? try if(isset($_POST['first_name'])) { ..

Comment: `if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)){ echo $_POST['first_name'];}` use this...

Comment: do you actually send any value in your input?

Comment: Show us more codes

Comment: I tried all of the above things. When doing.. 'print_r($_POST);' I get all of the variables in the array including first_name. When I try 'try if(isset($_POST['first_name']))' I put an echo hello statement in there and it did work. I also tried the last method by Manjeet and that echoed "Hi again," however anytime I try to actually print the text stored in the variable it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out the problem, and it was really stupid. My code had been working all along, but I wanted to test it so I just filled in the first entry, "first_name". It looks like you have to fill out the entire array in order to get a response. I should've done this from the start. Sorry, still a beginner.

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score -7):

Change the line:echo $_POST["first_name"];
with   echo $_POST['first_name'];

Comment: quotation characters play no role here